# Image Resource of an ImageView

Tags: android

After I set several images for my Gallery, I want to get all resource ids that have been used.
How do I get the Image Resources(int) of an ImageView inside a Gallery?

Thanks.

Comment: Show some code first of how you are setting the images.

Comment: Can you explain a little more